# ROLLBACK TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION error in sql server

Tags: sql, transactions

I am getting the error "ROLLBACK TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION". I am trying to rollback the transaction if the row count for any delete statement is zero. Given below is my code. What am I doing wrong? Please help

```
alter procedure delete_staff(@staffID varchar(10))
as
declare @tempvar varchar(50), @staffName varchar(50), @jobTitle varchar(50), @dept varchar(50)
begin transaction trans1
        declare @rc1 int
        declare @rc2 int
        declare @rc3 int
        select @tempvar = left(@staffID,1) from Staff
        delete from staff where staffID = @staffID
        set @rc1=@@rowcount
        delete from Login where userID = @staffID 
        set @rc2=@@rowcount
        begin
        if(@tempvar='S')
                begin
                delete from Specialist where specialistID = @staffID    
                set @rc3=@@rowcount
                end
        else if(@tempvar='H')
                begin
                delete from Helpdesk_Operator where helpdesk_OperatorID = @staffID
                set @rc3=@@rowcount
                end
        commit transaction trans1
        end
        if(@rc1=0 or @rc2=0 or @rc3=0)
        begin
        rollback transaction trans1
        end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you commit the transaction, you can't then make a rollback. Do one or the other:

```
if(@rc1=0 or @rc2=0 or @rc3=0)
begin
  rollback transaction trans1
end else begin
  commit transaction trans1
end
```

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Answer (score 4):

You have `commit transaction trans1` right before your if statement for the rollback.  The transaction will always be committed before you check the counts.

Answer (score 2):

This happens if your transaction has already been committed before you actually go into your commit statement.
You might give a condition 'If (@@TRANCOUNT>0)' before your 'COMMIT TRANSACTION' Statement.

For Eg:

```
 BEGIN TRANSACTION
  SELECT 0--Statements To Excecute
  ROLLBACK
  IF(@@TRANCOUNT>0)
  COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

OR

```
  BEGIN TRY
  BEGIN TRANSACTION
  SELECT 0 --Statements To Excecute     
  COMMIT TRANSACTION
  END TRY
  BEGIN CATCH
  IF(@@TRANCOUNT>0)
  ROLLBACK
  END CATCH
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the `commit transaction trans1` is always getting hit, therefore you will be unable to rollback from that point.